# how to insert backslash within double quotes in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

Python: Within a string e.g. "Hi"5"Hello" I want to insert (backslash) in front of double quotes. For the above example I want to insert "Hi\"5\"Hello". Is there some way to do so in python.

I have data of the form:

```
   <a> <b> "Hi"5"Hello"
   <c> <d> ""Way"toGo"
```

I want to convert this data to the form:

```
   <a> <b> "Hi\"5\"Hello"
   <c> <d> "\"Way\"toGo"
```

Comment: How do we know which `"` is the ending `"`?

Comment: @nhahtdh The double quotes have to be matched with each other implicitly. Also thanks a lot for replying

Comment: `matched with each other implicitly` I don't get what you mean. I am asking if you were to identify which `"` to escape and which not to, then how would you identify?

Comment: Does the string include the outer quotes or is that just your notation?

Comment: You want to escape all but the first and the last `"`.  Is that correct?

Comment: Why don't you just use `'` or `'''` ?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you want to escape all but the first and last `"` in the string.  If that's true, then we get something like:

```
>>> i1 = s.index('"')
>>> i2 = s.rindex('"')
>>> i1
0
>>> i2
11
>>> s[i1+1:i2]
'Hi"5"Hello'
>>> ''.join((s[:i1+1],s[i1+1:i2].replace('"',r'\"'),s[i2:]))
'"Hi\\"5\\"Hello"'
```

Comment: Why are we getting here two backslash instead of one i.e. can't I get the value as '"Hi\"5\"Hello"'

Comment: @user1778824 -- There's only 1 backslash in the string.  `print` the value instead.  (when you use `__repr__`, it puts extra backslashes in there).

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to get lost in character-escaping rules especially if you're flipping between Python, JavaScript, regex syntaxes etc. The easy way to do this in Python is to flag your string as "raw" using "r" notation:

Bad example:

```
>>> test = 'Hi \there \\friend \n good day'
>>> print test
Hi      here \friend 
 good day
```

Good example:

```
>>> test = r'Hi \there \\friend \n good day'
>>> print test
Hi \there \\friend \n good day
```